# How to exclude tag in shopify in default Search & Discovery Apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, shopify, liquid

I am tired to exclude tag in collections/all page i am create a one text area setting user can insert which tag want exclude and after than split the text area item assign in one variable but how to match this split item variable and how it possible in shopify filter Aap